# How to display status (ACTIVE, INACTIVE, IN REVIEW) instead of tinyint 0, 1, 2 in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm using cakephp 2.x. I've a status field in users table

> status (unsigned tinyint 2)

I want to use

> 0 = ACTIVE 
>    1 = INACTIVE 
>    2 = IN REVIEW

But when I get values with find query. It shows int value by default.

What is the best way to display the status as **ACTIVE, INACTIVE, IN REVIEW** in table instead of int value.

Comment: See [static-enums-or-semihardcoded-attributes/](http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/24/static-enums-or-semihardcoded-attributes/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `array` as a configuration like -

```
$status = array('ACTIVE', 'INACTIVE', 'IN REVIEW');
```

And print it like -

```
echo $status[0]; // ACTIVE - $status[$yourValue]
```

Comment: Thanks @b0s3. It's a nice trick. If I want to set the variable as global is the only way to declare it in AppController?

Comment: No need to do this in AppController. You can use `config` file in cakephp. Check the docs for that.